# How can I know if a DELETE request was completed successfully using SupaBase?

Tags: flutter, dart, supabase

If I make a request to delete, and the supplied id is not found in the db, how can I know that this operation did not complete successfully? The same goes for update and insert. I'm thinking of an optimal way, since for example, to find out if it was deleted correctly, I could make a query looking for that value, but it doesn't seem like the best way to me.

I tried to force the update by passing an id that doesn't exist, and, using the **onError** method, didn't catch any errors, even though it was displayed on the console.

```
.onError((error, stac) {
                      
                      return const Center(
                        child: Text('Error'),
                      );
```

Comment: In SQL it is not an error to delete a record that already isn't there. :)

Comment: You can use [single](https://supabase.com/docs/reference/dart/single) to check if there was a single row deleted(otherwise it will err and the transaction will rollback).

Comment: @SteveChavez could you provide an example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find out whether a delete operation succeded or not by wrapping your call with try/catch like this:

```dart
try {
  await supabase.from('table').delete().eq('id', '1');
} catch(error) {
  // error occured
  print(error);
}
```

However, as @Randal Schwartz have stated, trying to delete or update a row that does not exist does not throw an error in SQL or in Supabase. If you really need to know if the data exists in the first place, you would have to do a `select` operation to get the data.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way

```js
async function Delete(id) {
  try {
    const { error } = await supabase.from('my_table')
      .delete()
      .eq('id', id)
      .single();
      if(error) throw error;
      return 'Row deleted';
    } catch (error) {
      if(error.code == 'PGRST116') return 'Row not found';  
      return 'Something went wrong';    
    }
  }
}
```